# Change all the dropdown option' s value when the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering when i check the checkbox (Select all), can all the dropdowns be forced to select "Y"
if it's unchecked, all the dropdowns will be forced to select "N"

Many thanks.

```js
var check = $('#check');

check.onclick(function(){
$('.option') = "Y";
})
```

```html
<table id="table">
<th>
select all <input type="checkbox" id="check">
</th>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="option status">
<option>Y</option>
<option>N</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select class="option status">
<option>Y</option>
<option>N</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Orginally i have a table that show the total amount needs to be paid and payment in arrears

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#table").on('input', '.txtCal, .status', function() {
  calculate();
 });


  function calculate() {
  var calculated_total_sum = 0;
  var to_be_paid = 0;

   $("#table tr").each(function() {
   var get_textbox_value = $('.txtCal', this).val();
   var get_payment_status = $('.status', this).val();

    if (get_textbox_value && get_payment_status) {
    if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
      calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
    }

    if (get_payment_status === 'N') {
      to_be_paid += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
    }
  }
});
$(".total_sum_value").html(calculated_total_sum);
$(".arrears").html(to_be_paid);
 }

  calculate();

  });
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6 result">

<div class="input-group">
<p>
  <span class="input-group-addon">Total Payment</span>
  <span class="input-group-addon">$HKD</span>
  <span class="input-group-addon total_sum_value"></span></p>

  <br><br><br>
  <p>
  <span class="input-group-addon">In Arrears</span>
  <span class="input-group-addon">$HKD</span>
   <span  class="input-group-addon arrears"></span></p>


</div>
```

Each table row will have a select dropdown that consists of two option "Y" and "N". Originally, i have to manually change its table row option, and the payment in arrears will change accordingly.
For example, if the dropdown is "Y" which means paid, the amount of payment in arrears will decrease automatically.

Now after adding the select all function, to force all dropdowns to select "Y",for some reason the calculate function fail to work.
Any ideas

Comment: write a script and then when click, change all the drop down, cool right? so, where your script?

Comment: The answer is **yes**. Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common class to all the `select` and value to the `option`. Trigger a function  on checking the checkbox which will select all `Y` option.Use jquery 'prop' method to add the property

```js
function selectAll(elem) {
  if ($(elem).prop('checked')) {
    $('.selOptions option[value=Y]').prop('selected', true);
  } else {
    $('.selOptions option[value=N]').prop('selected', true);
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th>
    select all <input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this)">
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="selOptions">
    <option value = "Y">Y</option>
    <option value = "N">N</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="selOptions">
    <option value = "Y">Y</option>
    <option value = "N">N</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: one issue, when uncheck the box, can the option be selected as "N"

Comment: thanks, just one more issue, sorri, my original calculate function wont work after adding yr function. Have updated the question,plz hv a look,thanks

Comment: @tam this snippet is completely independent of your code. Also in your code I see `calculate()` is cqalled from two place

Comment: yes it's called in 2 place, as i want the amount of payment in arrears to be changed immediately when the payment status is changed(eg from N to Y)

Comment: right now when it's select all as 'Y'.the amount of payment in arrears wont change right away. from the db, i can see all Y is saved, so only i enter the page again will it show the correct amount of payment in arrears after paying.Is there any way i can trigger the change when the dropdown option are all selected?

Answer (score 1):

Using vainilla JS

```
<table>
    <th>
        select all <input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" />
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>
var selectAll = document.getElementById('selectAll');
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

selectAll.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        for(var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
            options[i].selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First determine when the checkbox is checked or not.

   - `$('#check').on('change', function() { if ($(this).is(':checked')) {...`
2. Then you could use a selector based on an `option`'s text content (you don't have a `value` attribute which you should but it's still functional.)

   - `$('option:contains(Y)')...`
3. Then use `.prop()` method to programmatically change it's `selected` state.

   - `.prop('selected', true);`

## Demo

```js
$('#check').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

    $('option:contains(Y)').prop('selected', true);

  } else {

    $('option:contains(N)').prop('selected', true);

  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <th>
    select all <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="option">
<option>--</option>
<option>Y</option>
<option>N</option>
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="option">
<option>--</option>
<option>Y</option>
<option>N</option>
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: well elaborated and explained answer.Thumb up!!